# How to programmatically click a link which use javascript in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, hyperlink

hello all i just so tired from searching all around the internet for a solution for this problem and i have used all the possibilities and it didn't worked
now here is the html code of the link

```
 <li id="jplain" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return usePlainText('draft');">HTML</a></li>
```

any help will be appreciated , thanks a lot

Comment: Is this from within a ASP.NET app? Windows App? Is this your own code why don't you just run the usePlainText('draft') javascript on postback? You need to provide a bit more information about what and how you are trying to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is too late to help you but I happened to see it with no solution.
In the following javascript code I have a click even associated with with a button(hdnF5) on the form. So this is the click event for say a button. It will do some things then fire another click
event on another control...perhaps a link or another button.

```
function FireClickEventFromSomeClickableControl() {
/* other instructions in here
   then finally getting to the
   last instruction below to 
   cause a click event on the
   control(the one you want the
   click event on) to fire.
*/

  document.form1.hdnF5.click();
}
```